# Changing minsdk version in android studio to enable use of RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

I am new to android development, and just learning. I am trying to create something with a RecyclerView, and the tutorial tells me I have to add these Gradle dependencies to my app's module:

```
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'
```

When adding them to the build.gradle file, I get an error saying I have an incompatible compileSdkVersion. I changed `compileSdkVersion 24` to `compileSdkVersion 21` but the error doesn't go, and I get an error on these:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0'
```

These are the rest of the settings that seem applicable to the sdk version in that file. Do I need to change any of those also in order to it to be compatible?

```
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "uk.ac.ncl.legacymakingv4"
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should always use the same version of everything in the `com.android.support` group. Therefore change your `cardview` and `recyclerview` to use the same `24.0.0` version.